# How can I send data to my Wamp server from my android application? (Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:....)

Tags: android, wamp

I am trying to create a registration Activity that sends user details to my wamp server but I am receiving an error that it cannot find the file i wrote in PHP(registration.php) to put the details in the database. I saved the registration.php file in C:\wamp\www\GolfStroke and my IP address is 192.168.1.11, my device and laptop are on the same network... Below is my JSONParser class:

```
package com.example.______.__________;

    import android.util.Log;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    /**
     * Created by Biko on 2/2/2016.
     */
    public class JSONParser {

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        DataOutputStream wr;
        StringBuilder result;
        URL urlObj;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        StringBuilder sbParams;
        String paramsString;

        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                          HashMap<String, String> params) {

            sbParams = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;
            for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                try {
                    if (i != 0){
                        sbParams.append("&");
                    }
                    sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                            .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }

            if (method.equals("POST")) {
                // request method is POST
                try {
                    urlObj = new URL(url);

                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                    //conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    //conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                    conn.connect();

                    paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                    wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET

                if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                    url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
                }

                try {
                    urlObj = new URL(url);

                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                    conn.setDoOutput(false);

                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                    conn.connect();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            try {
                //Receive the response from the server
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON Object
            return jObj;
        }
    }
```

This is my RegisterActivity class:

```
    package com.example._______._________;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Button regBtn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String Name = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameEditText)).getText().toString();
                final String Phone = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneEditText)).getText().toString();
                final String Email = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailEditText)).getText().toString();
                final String Password = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText)).getText().toString();

                class Register extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{

                    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

                    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                    private static final String RegURL = "http://192.168.1.11/GolfStroke/registration.php";

                    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
                    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute(){
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
                        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

                        try {
                            HashMap<String, String> details = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                            details.put("Name", Name);
                            details.put("Phone", Phone);
                            details.put("Email", Email);
                            details.put("Password", Password);

                            Log.d("Hashmap", "Mapping");

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(RegURL, "POST", details);

                            if (jsonObject != null){

                                Log.d("JSON result", jsonObject.toString());

                                return jsonObject;
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject){

                        int success = 0;
                        String message = "";

                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        if (jsonObject != null){
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, jsonObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            try {
                                success = jsonObject.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                                message = jsonObject.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        if (success == 1){
                            Log.d("success", message);
                        }else {
                            Log.d("Failure", message);
                        }
                    }


                }new Register().execute(Name, Phone, Email, Password);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

and below is my log:

> 02-02 10:50:49.753 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream D/Hashmap: Mapping
>   02-02 10:50:49.773 8456-8456/com.example.biko.golfstream D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
>   02-02 10:50:49.773 8456-8456/com.example.biko.golfstream D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
>   02-02 10:50:49.773 8456-8456/com.example.biko.golfstream D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
>   02-02 10:50:49.783 8456-8456/com.example.biko.golfstream D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.11/GolfStroke/registration.php
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at com.example.biko.golfstream.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:112)
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at com.example.biko.golfstream.RegisterActivity$1$1Register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:68)
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at com.example.biko.golfstream.RegisterActivity$1$1Register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:36)
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   02-02 10:50:50.263 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   02-02 10:50:50.273 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   02-02 10:50:50.273 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   02-02 10:50:50.273 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at com.example.biko.golfstream.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:130)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at com.example.biko.golfstream.RegisterActivity$1$1Register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:68)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at com.example.biko.golfstream.RegisterActivity$1$1Register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:36)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   02-02 10:50:50.283 8456-9265/com.example.biko.golfstream W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Does anyone know where I went wrong? All help is really appreciated!

Comment: Is the file accessible from the link http://192.168.1.11/GolfStroke/registration.php on another computer on that network?

Comment: the file should be accessible it is on my wamp server and i have turned of my firewall... both the laptop and device i am using to test are connected on the same network

Answer (score 1):

Try using `10.0.2.2` IP address instead of using `192.168.1.11`, if you are using local server.

**`http://10.0.2.2:<hostport>`**  for AVD and **`http://10.0.3.2:<hostport>`** for Genymotion!

Comment: I have tried changing the IP to that but then it just times out cos that is not the server IP..... I am using wamp server on my laptop and using a device connected on the same network to test...